# TclError: can't invoke "button" command

Tags: python, tkinter

This code is used to develop traffic sign classifier gui with various buttons to upload and classify an image. I used tkinter gui to add buttons to my python project as shown below:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import numpy as np
# load the trained model to classify sign
from  tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
model = load_model('my_model.h5')
top = tk.Tk()
top.geometry('800x600')
top.title('Traffic sign classification')
top.configure(background='#bad5ff')

label = Label(top, background='#bad5ff', font=('arial', 25, 'bold'))
sign_image = Label(top)
def classify(file_path):
    global label_packed
    image = Image.open(file_path)
    image = image.resize((32, 32))
    image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    image = np.array(image)
    print(image.shape)
    pred =np.argmax(model.predict([image]),axis=-1)[0]
    sign = classes[pred+1]
    print(sign)
    label.configure(foreground='#364156', text=("Result: "+sign))
def show_classify_button(file_path):
    classify_b = Button(top, text="  Classify Image  ",command=lambda: classify(file_path), padx=10, pady=5)
    classify_b.configure(background='#364156',foreground='#364156', font=('arial', 20, 'bold'))
    classify_b.place(relx=0.362, rely=0.925)
def upload_image():
    try:
        file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        uploaded = Image.open(file_path)
        uploaded.thumbnail(
            ((top.winfo_width()/2.25), (top.winfo_height()/2.25)))
        im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(uploaded)

        sign_image.configure(image=im)
        sign_image.image = im
        label.configure(text='')
        show_classify_button(file_path)
    except:
        pass      
    upload = Button(top, text="Upload an image",command=upload_image, padx=10, pady=5)
    upload.configure(background='#364156', foreground='#364156',font=('arial', 20, 'bold'))
    
    upload.pack(side=BOTTOM, pady=50)
    sign_image.pack(side=BOTTOM, expand=True)
    label.pack(side=BOTTOM, expand=True)
    heading = Label(top, text="Traffic Sign Recognition",pady=20, font=('arial', 25, 'bold'))
    heading.configure(background='#bad5ff', foreground='#364156')
    heading.pack()
    top.mainloop()
```

It should create a window with the specified buttons but i received an error message,which i do not understand.

```
TclError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [12], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 upload = Button(top, text="Upload an image",command=upload_image, padx=10, pady=5)
      2 upload.configure(background='#364156', foreground='#364156',font=('arial', 20, 'bold'))
      4 upload.pack(side=BOTTOM, pady=50)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py:2650, in Button.__init__(self, master, cnf, **kw)
   2631 def __init__(self, master=None, cnf={}, **kw):
   2632     """Construct a button widget with the parent MASTER.
   2633 
   2634     STANDARD OPTIONS
   (...)
   2648         overrelief, state, width
   2649     """
-> 2650     Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py:2572, in BaseWidget.__init__(self, master, widgetName, cnf, kw, extra)
   2570 for k, v in classes:
   2571     del cnf[k]
-> 2572 self.tk.call(
   2573     (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
   2574 for k, v in classes:
   2575     k.configure(self, v)

TclError: can't invoke "button" command: application has been destroyed
```

Since i am new to python and tkinter i am not able to fix this error. Where have i gone wrong in this code. Can anyone help me find out where i went wrong.

Comment: Please fix your formatting / indentation - this is a bit too dense to be easy to read

Comment: This looks like you've used your IDE to execute a fragment of the code by itself, without any of the necessary setup having been executed.  You need to run the entire script.

Comment: I suspect that the issue may be caused by `upload = Button(top, text="Upload an image",command=upload_image, padx=10, pady=5)` calling the function in which it's declared, i.e. `upload_image`. Try inserting the button at the root level instead of within the function it calls.